# How do I draw this noise / shadow effect in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows, noise

there is a dark effect on the yellow color in this photo 
would you mind help me to draw like it in illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Hi seyed, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my eye, it looks like the noise effect in Photoshop. It might be easier to build up layers of monochrome **Noise** with the blending mode **Multiply**. These then are built up using **Layer Masks** on to give the gradual build up from light to dark.